# Is there a Cordova plugin for OM SDK?

Tags: cordova, sdk, om

The IAB has a new SDK for measuring viewability in app, and they have launched the OM SDK. Do you know if there is a Cordova plugin for this or if maybe are there plans to develop it?

Here is the IAB article refering to OM SDK:
https://iabtechlab.com/standards/open-measurement-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried searching on the [Cordova Plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=iab) database?

Comment: Yes, but there’s nothing yet.